# Handling Unicode in string search

Tags: go

Suppose I have a string containing Unicode characters. For example:

```golang
s := "foo 日本 foo!"
```

I'm trying to find the last occurrence `foo` in the string:

```golang
index := strings.LastIndex(s, "foo")
```

The expected result here would be 7 but this will return 11 as the index due to the Unicode in the string.

Is there a way to handle this using standard library functions?

Comment: what do you mean by "handle this"? you wish the index to point to the *character* instead of the byte?

Comment: A really simple approach is this: https://play.golang.org/p/HTyx1D7Iky7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encountering the difference between **runes** in go and bytes. Strings are composed of bytes, not runes. If you haven't learned about this, you should read https://blog.golang.org/strings.

Here's my version of a quick function to calculate the number of runes preceding the last match of a substring in a string. The basic approach is to find the byte index, then iterate/count through the strings runes until that number of bytes have been consumed.

I'm not aware of a standard library method that will do this directly.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func LastRuneIndex(s, substr string) (int, error) {
    byteIndex := strings.LastIndex(s, substr)
    if byteIndex < 0 {
        return byteIndex, nil
    }
    reader := strings.NewReader(s)
    count := 0
    for byteIndex > 0 {
        _, bytes, err := reader.ReadRune()
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        byteIndex = byteIndex - bytes
        count += 1
    }
    return count, nil
}

func main() {
    s := "foo 日本 foo!"
    count, err := LastRuneIndex(s, "foo")
    fmt.Println(count, err)
    // outputs:
    // 7 <nil>
}
```

Comment: A more efficient function might be to avoid the initial `LastIndex` call and compare the next characters in the reader directly... it's something like O(2n) vs O(n) complexity difference so I'm not trying it.

Answer (score 0):

This gets pretty close:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/text/language"
   "golang.org/x/text/search"
)

func main() {
   m := search.New(language.English)
   start, end := m.IndexString("foo 日本 foo!", "foo")
   println(start == 0, end == 3)
}
```

buts it's searching forward. I tried this:

```
m.IndexString("foo 日本 foo!", "foo", search.Backwards)
```

but I get this result:

```
panic: TODO: implement
```

- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/search
- https://github.com/golang/text/blob/v0.3.6/search/search.go#L222-L223